# Cannot bind function to ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to append the function `ajaxFailureHandler` to the `ajax` request:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: GlobalVariables.baseUrl + '/dashboard_api/ajax_save_user',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'post',
    success: function (response) {

      alert(true);
    }.bind(this),
    error: function (response) {
        alert(false);
    }
}.bind(this), 'json').fail(GeneralFunctions.ajaxFailureHandler);
```

but I actually get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.bind is not a function

what can I do for fix this?

Comment: Why do you have a .bind(this) on the $.ajax call?

Comment: why you use `bind(this)`?

Comment: If you expect `json` response set `dataType:'json'`

Comment: @BrianMains I need to use some function of the module, I removed from the ajax call for lighten the code shown

Comment: seems like you would want `.fail(GeneralFunctions.ajaxFailureHandler.bind(this));`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've bound the settings object you're passing to $.ajax(). I think you probably meant to bind the error function like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: GlobalVariables.baseUrl + '/dashboard_api/ajax_save_user',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'post',
    success: function (response) {
      alert(true);
    }.bind(this),
    error: function (response) {
        alert(false);
    }.bind(this)
}, 'json').fail(GeneralFunctions.ajaxFailureHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context` option to change `this` in all the callbacks.

You don't need `error` if you use `.fail()`

Set `dataType:'json'` if you expect json response

```
$.ajax({

    context: this,// binds `this` in success and fail callbacks
    dataType: 'json',    

    url: GlobalVariables.baseUrl + '/dashboard_api/ajax_save_user',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'post',
    success: function (response) {
      alert(true);
    }
}).fail(GeneralFunctions.ajaxFailureHandler);
```